# How to Enable inactive webbook event?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I need some help understanding some issue regarding the webhooks.
1.When a webhooks change status to “reactivated “ do I get some message about it?
2.How I make sure all my webhooks are always active?
3.Can I enable a webhooks with status inactive?
4.When the “autoReactivateHook”  starting the count until 5 do I get some sort of a message to check if my endpoint has any issues

Answer (score 0):

1. When a webhooks change status to “reactivated “ do I get some
   message about it?

*No AFAIK.*

2. How I make sure all my webhooks are always active?

*Depending on how your hooks have been setup, some may have gotten disabled. We generally disable hooks that are calling URL's that are failing. See our [retry policy](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/developers_guide/event-delivery-guarantees/) for details. you may need to run a [query](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/http/webhooks/systems-system-events-event-hooks-GET/) looking for all hooks with an inactive status.*

3. Can I enable a webhooks with status inactive?

*Yes, use https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/http/systems-system-events-event-hooks-hook_id-PATCH/*

4. When the “autoReactivateHook”  starting the count until 5 do I get
   some sort of a message to check if my endpoint has any issues?

*This is done automatically and I don't think an extra message will be sent. you can use the [query](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/http/systems-system-events-event-hooks-GET/) as mentioned above.*